# Calling a MVC Model function from a console app within the same project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, console-application

Hey all I have a quick question here which I am unsure if it has an answer or not.

I have built an ASP.net MVC app that has a model named **Helper.cs**. Within this class I have a function called **callSQLSP**.

Now bundled with this ASP.net MVC app I created a C# console app. I am needing to be able to reference the **Helper.cs** function that's in my ASP.net MVC app inside my C# console app.

[image]

The **Helper.cs** class is used throughout the ASP.net MVC app so it's not just the case of copy that code out of the app and just place it into the console app.

Is this possible to do? Reason being is I don't want 2 copies of the same function where as if something were needed to be changed then I would have to change it in 2 places instead of just 1.

Comment: Move Helper.cs into a new Class Library project, then reference that project in both your MVC and Console projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move Helper.cs into a new Class Library project, then reference that project in both your MVC and Console projects.

[image]

You can then reference the class in either project:

```
using ClassLibraryProject;

namespace ConsoleProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Helper helper = new Helper();
            helper.CallSQLSP();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Put all common functions into a third project referenced by both MVC and console app. That's the 'standard' solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should aviod using helper classes. Helper classes are big candidates of god classes and it also violates SOLID principles. I suggest you to distribute every function to some other places. For example   CallSP function needs to be somewhere else in your data layer.